# Issue with SelectBox (country/state)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I got a problem.
I've tried to do a selectbox using boostrap form helpers.(http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/state.html)

So I got a selectbox for "country" and an other for "state"

```
<select id="countries" class="form-control bfh-countries"></select>
<select id="states" class="form-control bfh-states" data-country="countries"></select>
```

If I choose a value form the country box the states appears in the states box, so everything ok.

But if I use a script

```
<button onclick="test()" class="btn">Load Country</button>

function test(){
            document.getElementById('countries').value = "AU";
        }
```

Nothing appends on the "states" selectbox, I should get the states of the country selected by the function test() right ?

What can I do to fix this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/xf8ech7k/1/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem there is that you aren't triggerent the "change" event.

Take a look at you modified [code](http://jsfiddle.net/omzayjbg/)

```js
function test(){
    var select = document.getElementById('countries')
    , event = document.createEvent("UIEvents");
    select.value = "AU";
    event.initUIEvent("change", true, true);
    select.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Then, take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789423/trigger-onchange-event)

As @CBroe says, you can do it in a simpler way by doing:

```
$("select").val("AU").trigger("change");
```

Comment: Since bootstrap uses jQuery already, that could be done much simpler, `$('#countries').val('AU').trigger('change');`

Comment: Thanks a lot, been 2 days I was searching :( and thanks for the link !!
Cheers

Comment: @Mindastic I've tried to modify my form with a flag in the selectbox, but when I trigged the value the flag don't appears, I just got the value. Is there  something to add in this case ? http://jsfiddle.net/xf8ech7k/2/

Comment: Given the fact that it is a custom plugin, you could do something like this: $('#countries').find('[data-option=AU]').trigger('click');

Comment: Works Perfect :) so trigger() can have different parameters, can we add like focus, blur ... is there any restrictions ? I'm going to play with trigger()

Comment: Yup, you can also trigger custom events. Check ".trigger()" doc for more information: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Thank you so much, it's pretty powerful ^^
Cheers