# How to click on selectbox options using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, click, phantomjs, html-select

There is the page [testkrok.org.ua](https://testkrok.org.ua/?lang=en) with a consistent selection of parameters. So, I need to create a series of 5 clicks on each of the options of 5 select boxes that depend on each other.

```
document.querySelector('select.se1')[3]
document.querySelector('select.se2')[1]
document.querySelector('select.se3')[1]
document.querySelector('select.se4')[1]
document.querySelector('select.se5')[3]
```

to redirect to the page with tests.

But on snapshot taken after the first click the second panel does not appear?
Maybe I don't hit the the element?

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://testkrok.org.ua', function(status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    if(status === "success") {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            var theEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
            theEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            var element = document.querySelector('select.se1')[3];
            element.dispatchEvent(theEvent);
        });
    }
    setTimeout( function() {
        page.render('snapshot.png');
        phantom.exit()
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to click on select box options. I don't think those aren't actually clickable. Also, you may need to wait a little after the click.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Add `setTimeout` for 5 sec., but also nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't click (trigger a click event) on options of a select box. You need to change the selected option and then [trigger a change event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8789494/1816580). For example:

```
var sel = document.querySelector('select.se1');
sel.selectedIndex = 2;
var event = new UIEvent("change", {
    "view": window,
    "bubbles": true,
    "cancelable": true
});
sel.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You can package that in a function

```
function selectOption(selector, optionIndex) {
    page.evaluate(function(selector, optionIndex){
        var sel = document.querySelector(selector);
        sel.selectedIndex = optionIndex;
        var event = new UIEvent("change", {
            "view": window,
            "bubbles": true,
            "cancelable": true
        });
        sel.dispatchEvent(event);
    }, selector, optionIndex);
}
```

Then you can call it one after the other

```
selectOption("select.se1", 2);
selectOption("select.se2", 0);
selectOption("select.se3", 0);
...
```

You get the idea. In case the `onChange` event of the select box needs remote data for example through AJAX, then you will need to wait between the calls. Either use a static wait time (see following example) or use [`waitFor()`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js).

```
setTimeout(function(){
    selectOption("select.se1", 2);
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){
    selectOption("select.se2", 0);
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){
    selectOption("select.se3", 0);
}, 3000);
...
```

Comment: After this change there is selected field on the snapshot but the second select tag does not appear
and it returns me an error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByTagName('option')[2].parentElement')`

Comment: and it does not work even in Firefox console, that is some JS magic

Comment: Yes, triggering a change event is necessary. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, thats work. Maybe you even know how to push the `document.querySelector('p.start_button')` ?

Comment: If you mean triggering a click, then you already tried that in your question using the MouseEvent.