# Dropdown Manipulation in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, html-select

I am trying to submit a form, consistent solely of a dropdown menu in order to get to another page. I cannot figure out how to select the dropdown however. The below sample is a representation of what I am dealing with.

```html
<select name="p_term" size="1" id="term_input_id">
<option value="">None
</option><option value="201605">Summer Session: May - Aug 2016
</option><option value="201601">Second Term: Jan - Apr 2016
</select>
```

I have tried

```
document.getElementById('term_input_id').value='201601';
```

but PhantomJS will not run the rest of my code with this line in there.

Comment: Does [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32771797/1816580) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30988637/1816580) work?

Answer (score 2):

`select` elements are not like inputs, you cannot assign value directly.

```
var val = 201601;
var sel = document.getElementById('term_input_id');
var opts = sel.options;
for(var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {
    if(opt.value == val) {
        sel.selectedIndex = j;
        // or:
        // opt.selected = true
        break;
    }
}
```

*(From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7373115/2715393) excellent answer)*

Then, you have to trigger `onchange` event that is redirecting page to another location:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
sel.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

*(From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856602/2715393) answer)*

> but PhantomJS will not run the rest of my code with this line in there.

To find out what error is causing your script to break, subscribe to [page.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) callback.

Comment: @ArtjomB. if it's fired with a `change` event on `<select>`, then to compose and dispatch the event programmatically is the way to go.

Comment: @ArtjomB, thanks, you're right, the answer was useless, updated with example to trigger `change` event.